# How to load multiple photos programmatically from an Android phone with Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to programmatically load multiple photos (say the latest 20 by date) with Xamarin.Android, without a user's interaction (i.e. not manually pick photos from a displayed collection).

Is it possible do this? Any sample code that I may use?

BTW, I know the code below, but that requires a user to pick a photo:

```
intent.SetType("image/*");

intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);

MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **MediaStore** to get the path of image .

```
Android.Net.Uri mImageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri;
            ContentResolver mContentResolver = ContentResolver;


var mCursor = mContentResolver.Query(mImageUri, null,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MimeType + "=? or "
                    + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MimeType + "=?",
                    new String[] { "image/jpeg", "image/png" }, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DateModified);


while (mCursor.MoveToNext())
{               
  var imagePath = mCursor.GetString(mCursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data));

  // do something you want 
}
```